# MATLAB curve smoothing

Tags: matlab, curve, smoothing

I have a smooth plot of wheel profile, but for a certain length there's a region in which the curve is not smooth. I need to smooth that region without affecting the profile co-ordinates of nearby points. Is there any way ? I have tried smoothing and curve fitting but its not serving my purpose.

Below is the image of the region to smooth:

[image: signal image]

Comment: Post the links, we'll have edit them in.

Comment: well from the looks of things, you could probably weed out this area using derivatives of the curve. Could you include the data too?

Comment: Actually I want to consider the peaks of that region too. (It is okay if JUST nearby points of that region gets affected)

Comment: Could you maybe draw on what you want to obtain? Have you tried Gaussian smoothing (convolution) with different widths?

Comment: Like this [link] (oi59.tinypic.com/vjszn.jpg)

Comment: Can you specify the region to be smoothed? If so you could try some sort of frequency filter. Perhaps a lowpass butterworth filter  (Frequency depends on your data). If you can't specify this region, you will always affect all data. It might still work if the characteristics are different from the rest of the curve. Without data or more information this is just guessing.

Comment: Sorry to be rude but IMO I actually se no reason to smooth the data. It seems like data corruption which, if it is official test data, in best case would be bad and in worst case illegal. But still this is not what you ask for so what I would do would be to transform the data to frequecy domain an see if there are difference in frequency for this other part

Comment: @Mo3bius and will,  Well I have the data points of the region, but I sort of got what I wanted but not exactly but it will serve my purpose. I filtered the uneven data using gaussian filter and then did a curve smoothing for the whole profile, which is sort of giving me a smooth curve. Thanks for the help !!

Comment: @patrik I will give your method a try, and about the data, its being generated by my program only.